# Pass parameter from Local to Sudo user

Tags: shell, unix

Ok if subject is not clear i will explain my doubt.I have a shell script kept at my local user called (**executeAdM.sh**), and when i execute this script i am connecting to **SUDO user** by taking commands from instruction file.But when i execute this script i am also passing **parameter** to this script which is actually some **directory path** of SUDO user. See the script below-:

Script at local(executeADM.sh) -:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo password | sudo -S -l
sudo /usr/bin/su - user  <<\EOF
#ls -lrt
pwd
for entry in $(ls -r)
  do
  if [ "$entry" = "testingADM.sh" ];then
./$entry $1
fi
done
EOF
```

Executing Above as-:

```
./executeADM.sh somePath
```

When above script executes it connects successfully to another user, and at **SUDO user**  i execute a for loop which search for another SCRIPT called **testingADM.sh** . Once the script is found i execute that script with parameter passed from Local User and  **testingADM.sh** should set that path for me which is not working it is not reading prameter passed from local user.Can anyone help me here i am not getting how to solve this. Please ask me if anything is not clear basically i want to pass parameter from **LOCAL** shell script to **SUDO USER** shell script-:

SUDO user script (**testingADM.sh**)-:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1
cd $path
pwd
```

If i hard code path variable value in script kept at SUDO all works fine . But i don't want that.:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 path=somepath
 cd $path
 pwd
```

Comment: You should quote `$1` like `path="$1"` to prevent reinterpretation of special characters

Comment: @NullDev already tried that but didn't worked.

Comment: @Tushar , Can u write all inside a script with  functions instead of separate scripts?

Comment: @KaushikNayak there are 2 different scripts kept at 2 different user one at local and one at sudo. So i do need seprate scripts one execute at local enviornment ,and after connection to sudo user execute script in that enviornment to make work easy, but i am stuck at passing parameter from local to Sudo.

Comment: This question has already been answered on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/1237547/

Comment: Closing this question, as it's been cross-posted on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Please see: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @NullDev A variable on the right-hand side of an assignment doesn't have to be quoted.